# Multisite hide subdirectory

Tags: redirect, domain-mapping

I have a multi site install using sub directories and Im using domain mapping.

The second site is like such domain.com/site2 and thats mapped to mywebsite.com

I can visit domain.com/site2 or mywebsite.com and both sites are being indexed by google - how can I make domain.com/site2 redirect to mywebsite.com so domain.com/site2 is not visible to users or search engines, only mywebsite.com is visible?

Comment: You need to edit your .htaccess file. Read about it here: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you.

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://www.your-url.com/
```

Comment: Everyone understand it that what is it. But may be good for newbies if you add that what do you mean by _something_.